# Programmatically execute button 2 click on click of button 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/d2rg3/)

wherein I want to perform `click` event of button 2 on `click` of button 1. Any help is highly appreciated and immediately learnt .

Comment: please post relevant code in question!

Comment: sorry guys I will close this delete this question , my bad!

Comment: having answers can't be deleted

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I did not put my efforts in researching the problem before, my bad

Comment: Don't worry, man. Just chill. This question helped other guys to earn extra votes. :D

Comment: lol ! everyone bombarded the little learner man. Thx for the support :P

Comment: +1 for little learner man :p

Comment: thanku muneeb I will make sure I will ask a good question next time.

Comment: @Ajey - You know you can actually edit your question...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$('#button').click();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2rg3/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$( "#button1" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( "#button2" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d2rg3/7/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $('#button').click()
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){
   alert("hello")

});
```

what i understand, try the above Code/ [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d2rg3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Please be thorough about what you actually want to achieve. And in your fiddle I can see that you have not done anything. Atleast try something and then if you are not able to do it the way you want to then only knock the stackoverflow door.

[Anyways, check this fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/d2rg3/5/)

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    alert("supposed to be clicked");
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('#button').trigger("click");

});
```